# Visual Studio 2017->2019 C/C++ Formatting Spaces After Ampersand Operator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When switching from VS2017 to VS2019 I imported our teams settings using the Import and Export Settings Wizard. With VS2019 I am seeing unwanted formatting when using (ctrl+k, ctrl+d) Format Document. This is using the C language.

I have searched through VS2019 C/C++ formatting settings and compared this to the settings on VS2017. They are the same.

In particular I am getting spaces after the ampersand in my c code.

```c
socket_recv(sock, (char *)&response_header, sizeof(response_header);
```

turns into

```c
socket_recv(sock, (char *)& response_header, sizeof(response_header));
```

This space isn't added using the same formatting settings in VS2017.

Answer (score 2):

This bug will be fixed.

[Wrong code formatting with ampersand operator](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/582083/wrong-code-formatting-with-ampersand-operator.html)

Comment: Should be available today, 16.3.0 was released last Monday.